# how to grep nth string

Tags: unix, awk, grep

How to use `"grep"` shell command to show specific word from a line starting with a specific word.

Ex: 
I want to print a string `"myFTPpath/folderName/"` from the line starting with `searchStr` in the below mentioned line.

```
searchStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring
```

Comment: for more accuracy use:
`awk -F: '/^searchStr:/{print $3}' File`

this will prevent confusion between searchStr and searchStr2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this with `awk`:

```
awk -F: '/^searchStr/{print $3}' File
```

From all the lines starting with `searchStr`, print the `3rd` field (field seperator set as `:`)

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
someStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring
someStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring
searchStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring
someStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring
AMD$ awk -F: '/^searchStr/{print $3}' File
myFTPpath/folderName/
```

Comment: @webDev: or if you want to use a variable: `n=3; awk -v col=$n -F: '/^searchStr/{print $col}' File`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `grep` isn't the only tool that can usefully do searches.

In this particular case, where the lines are naturally broken into fields, `awk` is probably the best solution, as @A.M.D's answer suggests.

For more general case edits, however, remember `sed`'s `-n` option, which suppresses printing out a line after edits:

```
sed -n 's/searchStr:[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/p' input-file
```

The `-n` suppresses automatic printing of the line, and the trailing `/p` flag explicitly prints out lines on which there *is* a substitution.

This matching pattern is fiddly – use `awk` in this fielded case – but don't forget `sed -n`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the desired output with `grep` itself but you need to enable `-P` and `-o` parameters.

```
$ echo 'searchStr:somestring:myFTPpath/folderName/:somestring' | grep -oP '^searchStr:[^:]*:\K[^:]*'
myFTPpath/folderName/
```

`\K` discards the characters which are matched previously from printing at the final leaving only the characters which are matched by the pattern exists next to `\K`. Here we used `\K` instead of a variable length positive lookbehind assertion.